# Access The 1st object in the pipe powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, pass-by-value

i created two functions in Powershell, the 1st function function get a registry key, if exist return computername and boolan, the 2nd get a list of installed windows updates and validate if some update exist.... and return computername and boolan allso..
now the problem is that whan i try to access to the 1st object in the pipe i get null...

```
Function Get-RegKey {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    "By OhadH 2012"
.DESCRIPTION
    Read Key From Registry and create it if not exist
.PARAMETER LiteralPath
.EXAMPLE
    Get-RegKey -strMachine "127.0.0.1" -Location "Software\\MyKey" -strValue "Type" -strValueToSearch "Server"
        Read The Registry key from "HKLM\Software\MyKey" the value Type and search for the value "Server"
.EXAMPLE
    Get-RegKey "127.0.0.1" "Software\\MyKey" "Type" "Server"
        Read The Registry key from "HKLM\Software\MyKey" the value Type and search for the value "Server"
        By Postion and not by value name
.NOTES
Author: OhadH
Date:   Feb 09, 2012    
#> 
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true,Position=0,ValueFromPipeline=$true)][String]$strMachine,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true,Position=1)][String]$Location,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true,Position=2)][String]$strValue,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true,Position=3)][String]$strValueToSearch
        )
    begin { $obj = New-Object psobject }
    process {
        try {
            $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty 'strMachine' $strMachine -Force
            $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $strMachine)
            $regKey = $reg.OpenSubKey($Location,$true) 
            $RegRead = $regKey.GetValue($strValue)
            if ($RegRead -eq $strValueToSearch) { $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty 'RegExist' $true -Force }
              else { $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty 'RegExist' $false -Force }
             }
         catch [System.Exception] { $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty 'RegExist' "!!Error!!" -Force } 
    }
    end { return $obj }
}

Function Set-RegKey { 
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    "By OhadH"
.DESCRIPTION
    Create Registry Key 
.PARAMETER LiteralPath
.EXAMPLE
    Set-RegKey -strMachine "127.0.0.1" -Location "Software\\MyKey" -strValue "Type" -strValueToSet "Server"
        Read The Registry key from "HKLM\Software\MyKey" the value Type and search for the value "Server"
.EXAMPLE
    Get-RegKey "127.0.0.1" "Software\\MyKey" "Type" "Server"
        Read The Registry key from "HKLM\Software\MyKey" the value Type and search for the value "Server"
        By Postion and not by value name
.NOTES
Author: OhadH
Date:   Feb 09, 2012    
#> 
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true,Position=0,ValueFromPipeline=$true)][String]$strMachine,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true,Position=1)][String]$Location,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true,Position=2)][String]$strValue,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true,Position=3)][String]$strValueToSet
        )
    begin { $obj = New-Object psobject }
    process {
        try {
            $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty 'strMachine' $strMachine -Force
            $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $strMachine)
            $reg.CreateSubKey($Location) | Out-Null
            $regKey = $reg.OpenSubKey($Location,$true) 
            $regKey.SetValue($strValue,$strValueToSet,"String")  
             }
         catch [System.Exception] { } 
    }
    end { }
}

Function Get-WindowsUpdate {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    "By OhadH"
.DESCRIPTION
    Get specific Installed KB
.PARAMETER LiteralPath
.EXAMPLE
    Get-WindowsUpdate -strMachine 127.0.0.1 -strUpdate "KB2633952"
        Get if KB2633952* installed on local machine
.EXAMPLE
    Get-WindowsUpdate 127.0.0.1 "KB2633952"
        Get if KB2633952* installed on local machine
.NOTES
Author: OhadH
Date:   Feb 09, 2012    
#> 
    param (
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true,Position=0,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][String]$strMachine,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true,Position=1,ValueFromPipeline=$true)][String]$strUpdate
    )
    begin { $obj = New-Object psobject }
    process {
            try {
                $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty 'strMachine' $strMachine -Force
                if ((gwmi -ComputerName $strMachine Win32_QuickFixEngineering | ? {$_.HotFixID -like $strUpdate+"*"}) -ne $null)
                    { $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty 'KBInstalled' $true -Force }
                 else { $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty 'KBInstalled' $false -Force }        
             }
             catch [System.Exception] { $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty 'KBInstalled' "!!Error!!" -Force }          
    }
    end { return $obj }
}

$subnet = '10.0.0.'
for ($i=1; $i -le 250; $i++) {
 $cntIP = $subnet + $i
 if ($cntIP = ($cntIP | Ping-Host -icmp | where { $_.Responding }).IPAddress) {
    Set-RegKey -strMachine $cntIP "SOFTWARE\\MyKey" -strValue "Type" -strValueToSet "Server"
    Get-RegKey -strMachine $cntIP "SOFTWARE\\MyKey" -strValue "Type" -strValueToSearch "Server" | Get-WindowsUpdate -strUpdate "KB2633952"  | select strMachine,**@{N="RegExist";E={$_.RegExist}},**KBInstalled
 }
}
```

Thanks for the help Ohad

Comment: Which part of all of this is giving you problems? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: whan i try to access the 1st element in the pipe... `Get-RegKey -strMachine $cntIP "SOFTWARE\\MyKey" -strValue "Type" -strValueToSearch "Server" | Get-WindowsUpdate -strUpdate "KB2633952" | select strMachine,@{N="RegExist";E={$_.RegExist}},KBInstalled` i want to get the **RegExist** value from the 1st pipeline. if i get the functions one by one i can access all the properties... but in pipe i can't access the values in **RegExist**

Comment: P.S: The **RegExist** is a value that Get-RegKey return

Answer (score 0):

If I follow, you need to pipe Get-RegKey to Foreach-Object and inside foreach save a reference to the object you want. If you have a pipeline made of three commands (e.g get-something | do-something | set-something) then the third cmdlet in the pipeline (e.g set-something) can't access object from an upstream cmdlet (e.g get-something).

Comment: did you mean some thing like that? `PS C:\> Get-RegKey -strMachine $cntIP "SOFTWARE\\MyKey" -strValue "Type" -strValueToSearch "Server" | % { Get- WindowsUpdate $_.strMachine -strUpdate "KB2633952"} | select strMachine,@{N="RegExist";E={$_.RegExist}},KBInstalled`...
P.S: You have a great blog...

Comment: Toda Ohad :). Yes exactly like that, inside foreach you can assign the current object to a variable and use it later in the code.

Comment: i did a rethinking about the way to pool the value in the most "Powershell" way and this what i found :) 

`Get-RegKey -strMachine $cntIP "SOFTWARE\\MyKey" -strValue "Type" -strValueToSearch "Server" | select strMachine,@{N="KBInstalled";E={(Get-WindowsUpdate -strMachine $_.strMachine -strUpdate "KB2633952").KBInstalled}},RegExist`

Thank you for your help...